# Getting the time difference using LINQ from a list of TimeSpans and parsing the time in as only minutes and seconds

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, time

Hi guys i have a string Enumerable which consist of laptimes in this format "00:30" "1:50" (min:sec). And my ultimate goal is to return an enumerable that consists of TimeSpans of time differences between each time with these string objects converted into TimeSpans.

So for example if we have this: "00:30" "1:50" " "2:00" this will return 00:30 , 1:20 , 0:10.

I currently have this:

```
var laps = lapTimes.Select(s => TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, "mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

But it is not able to parse it. Also i dont know how i would do the time difference using linq   because if i try subtracting the current time span from the one in the next index eventually i will receive an index out of bound exception.

Thanks , would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `DateTime.ParseExact`. Then you can use the indexer of the ordered `List` to access the previous `TimeSpan` and subtract it from the next `TimeSpan`:

```
var lapTimes = new[]{"00:30", "1:50","2:00"};
var laps = lapTimes.Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "m:ss", null).TimeOfDay)
    .OrderBy(ts => ts)
    .ToList();
var diffs = laps.Take(1)   // take the first fix TimeSpan
    .Concat(laps.Skip(1).Select((ts, i) => ts - laps[i])) // add all differences
    .ToList();
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/MA0Onu)</kbd>

**Edit**: For the sake of completeness, i always forget that you need to escape the colons in `TimeSpan.ParseExact`, so this works also:

```
var laps = lapTimes.Select(s => TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, @"m\:ss", null))
    ....
```

Details: [**Custom TimeSpan Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think LINQ fits to your case, when you need  the previous item while iterating.

```
string format = @"h\:mm";
string[] laps = new[]{"00:30", "1:50", "2:00"};

var spans = new List<TimeSpan>();
spans.Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(laps[0], format, null));

for (int i = 1; i < laps.Length; i++)
{
    spans.Add(
        TimeSpan.ParseExact(laps[i   ], format, null) -
        TimeSpan.ParseExact(laps[i -1], format, null)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
One solution:

string[] lapTimes = { "00:30", "1:50", "2:00"};
var laps = lapTimes.Select(s => s.Split(":".ToCharArray()));
var times = laps.Select(s=> new TimeSpan(0, int.Parse(s[0]), int.Parse(s[1]))).Reverse();
List<TimeSpan> diffs = new List<TimeSpan>();
for (int i = 0; i < times.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    diffs.Add(times.ElementAt(i) - times.ElementAt(i+1));            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not LINQ, but this can also be done with a `foreach` loop:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
stringList.Add("00:30");
stringList.Add("01:50");
stringList.Add("02:00");

List<TimeSpan> timeSpanList = new List<TimeSpan>();
TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

foreach (string item in stringList)
{
    ts1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(item, @"mm\:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    if (ts2.Equals(new TimeSpan(0,0,0)))
    {
        timeSpanList.Add(ts1);
    }
    else
    {
        timeSpanList.Add(ts1 - ts2);
    }

    ts2 = ts1;
}
```